# How to use global variables like $host in included file?

Tags: nginx

I include part of configuration in my major configuration file

```
include /some/path/log.conf;
```

In that file I try to use $host variable

```
error_log /some/path/$host.error.log;
```

But it creates "$host.error.log" file instead of using variable.

How can I use global variables in included files?

I thought that's a simple question, but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Does `$HOSTNAME.error.log` work?

Comment: You are implying that it does work in the main file.  Does it ?

Comment: @RohitGupta it works in the main file, but doesn't work, when I put it in separate file

Answer (score 2):

From
[Using Environment Variables in Nginx Config File](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/nginx-config-environment-variables):

> [nginx.conf](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/) contains config related to our Nginx server. The Nginx config doesn’t support environment variables out of the box. However, there are tools and workarounds that we can use to carry out this process for us.
>
> [envsubst](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/envsubst-command) is a tool that we can use to generate an Nginx config file dynamically before the server starts. It replaces variables in a text with the corresponding values of our shell variables.
>
> Moreover, it’s not a standalone utility. It comes with the gettext metapackage. So, by default, it will already be available on our Linux machine.

Using `envsubst` is described in the above article for creating
a dynamic Nginx config file that contains environment variables,
instead of hardcoded values.

Comment: I have a needed variable $host, but it's not passes to a include file

Comment: @Vladimir Then please read this answer again and look into using [`envsubst`](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/envsubst-command) to generate an `nginx.conf` file before Nginx starts that can use environment variables.